# What should my job title actually be?

Tags: new-job, title

Recently I joined a company, but I have a question regarding my job title. I think my job title should be different because the current one feels more like a subset of my actual work.

My current job title is 'Full-Stack Developer'. To me, in short, it feels like Full Stack Developers design and develop the front-end, back-end, and everything in between.

My actual work consists of:

- Meeting (continuously) with the customer to gather and coordinate their needs and requirements
- Creating functional and technical design documents utilizing UML/ERD diagrams
- Developing the front-end, back-end, and everything in between (Full-Stack)
- Setting up, maintaining, and utilizing the CI/CD infrastructure using GitLab, Docker, and AWS
- Maintaining and supporting the application after the project is 'done'

Basically, everything that is needed from a customer's wish to the project delivery including the support afterward.

I wonder if the title 'Full Stack Developer' covers my actual workload. If not, what should my job title actually be? I have tried searching the internet, but I can't find anything this broad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ask your manager ?

Comment: I wish, he doesn't know. I had to explain to him what DevOps was... He is the one that put up the job offer with that title.

Comment: The only other title I can come up with is just Software Developer, which is broader, more generic term. But I guess this doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: I always thought that developer do all those things described by you. But maybe I just have a small company perspective.

Comment: **What should my job title actually be?** - I mean... does it really matter? What would a title change accomplish? What impact on your job would it have?

Comment: @PiotrGolacki Agree with you. In a smaller company or less technical focused company then a fullstack devloper will handle all the things mentioned above. In a bigger company it would probably be more focused on specific areas like only FE and BE for a project instead of the infrastructure etc as well. But the title I think is correct

Answer (score 3):

You wrote your one of your tasks is "**Developing the front-end, back-end, and everything in between (Full-Stack)**".

So, I guess your job title should be "**Full-Stack Developer**".

The important thing to remember is that when you interview for your next job in the future, that company will ask you to describe your work at your current company, and they will give you coding tests to verify your skills and experiences. So, as long as you are honest about your skills and experiences on your resume, you are fine.

---

(PS: Is there any reason you don't think this "Full Stack Developer" is the correct title ?)

Comment: Agree and disagree, one of the tasks is being a full stack developer, yes. But I do more than that. When a supermarket is searching for a stock clerk, but when the actual workload consists of managing the people that work there, being a cashier, and doing warehouse work loading and unloading trucks, then the title 'stock clerk' is not the right one.

Comment: You can list your job title as full stack developer. In addition, in your resume, you can provide more details about the extra tasks that you take on at this current job.

Answer (score 0):

#### Job Titles don't mean anything.

Worry about your responsibilities and accomplishments, which is what will go on your resume.  If your title were Senior Vice President of Full Stack Operations it wouldn't change what you actually do.

And as it is, your job title sounds very accurate to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong with job titles. This is my take on it:

> Basically, everything that is needed from a customer's wish to the project delivery including the support afterward.

I would say that is a software developer. Any good education should teach all of that, so that you can open up your own shop and sell software without needing anybody else if you don't want to.

Fullstack Developer is the same thing, I would just expect a company to have "non-fullstack" developer, too, if they felt the need to make a distinction. Just like I would expect a company to have more than one type of cook if they employ a "schnitzel cook". I would expect another type of cook. Otherwise it's *the* cook. No distinction neccessary.

When does the job evolve into business analyst, project manager, software architect, network enginer, customer support agent? From my point of view, when you do it *for someone else*. So if you do customer requirements for someone that is *not* you, *then* from my point of view, a title like business analyst might be in order. If you plan the projects or lay out the arcitecture for projects that are not just yours, but are actually developed by a team, that might not even include you, *then* a title of project manager or software architect makes sense.

In my eyes, "Software Developer" is the correct title. And feel free to mention all of this when you tell people what you do/did for the company. It's good information and valuable experience. There is a reason we list more than just the job title in CVs.